# Assign custom lombok builder method as singular handler

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following table class which makes usage of `@Builder` Lombok annotation with a custom builder class:

```java
@Builder
public class MyTable {
    ...
    public static class MyTableBuilder {
        public void entry(final MyEntry myEntry) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In another class that is composed by `MyTable` I would like to make usage of `@Builder` + `@Singular` annotations so that I can build `TableOwner` instances specifying entry by entry.

```java
@Builder
public class TableOwner {
    @Singular("entry")
    private final MyTable entries;
}
```

```java
TableOwner.builder()
        .entry(...)
        .entry(...)
        .entry(...)
        .build()
```

However the `@Singular` annotation on `entries` results the error "*Lombok does not know how to create the singular-form builder methods for type 'MyTable'; they won't be generated.*".

Is there a way I can point to `MyTableBuilder#entry` method as the singular handler for `entries`?

Comment: `@Singular` only works for collections like `Set`, `List`, or `Map`. Lombok cannot know how to instantiate and populate your `MyTable`. You have to write that builder singular methods manually.

Comment: @Singular also works for guava `Table`, but indeed the support is built-in Lombok. However I already created the method that can handle the singular setter (`MyTable#entry`). I was expecting that with other annotation (let's say `@SingularMethod`) I could mark `entry` method.